# bazel build error when following tf tutorial 'usage with c++ api'

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following error messages

```
~/tensorflow$ bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image/...
ERROR: /home/dooseop/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl:497:19: name 
'DATA_CFG' is not defined.
ERROR: error loading package '': Extension 'tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl' 
has errors.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.144s
```

when I try to follow the tutorial privided in https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition

Some people (who receive the same error messages when build tensorflow with bazel) say 'upgrade bazel and try again'.

However, the advise doesn't work for me..Is there anyone who can tell me how to solve the problem?

Note that I installed 1) bazel 0.5.0 2)tensorflow 1.1.0 under ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed strange, HOST_CFG was removed from Bazel [0.4.4](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/a3e26835890a543ff84cce90c879f9196ae06348/CHANGELOG.md#release-044-2017-02-01), so a while ago. As far as I know Tensorflow already fixed its uses.

Maybe if you used older version of Bazel before, try running `bazel clean --expunge` just in case old Bazel left an inconsistent output tree. We did fix a bug there recently.

Or try latest Tensorflow 1.2rc0 or github HEAD.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!!! The problem was 'tensorflow should be installed from its source!!' I had installed tensorflow by pip method!! That was the core of the problem. Thank you very much :)